# Two column checkers with CSS nth-child

Tags: css

I have a form that is divided into two columns with floats.  I want to make them "checkered".  How can I use nth-child to achieve this?  See the screenshot below to see what I mean.  Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
    Grade Calculator
</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .form-group {
            padding: 15px;
            width: 45%;
            float: left;
        }
        .form-group:nth-child(3n+0){
            background: #e4e4e4;
        }
        form {
            margin: 25px auto;
            border-width: 0px 1px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #ccc;
            width: 50%;
        }
        label {
            width: 350px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: block;
        }
        input {
            width: calc(100% - 20px);
            margin: 15px 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./Default.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="Era4Q8Ttswx16Rg3XXwdNh7LuVHYalpdgKUCOJGwMcgBX7OP6eVRcScpUQ68BMteFlRltJ8L3vXUMx8wG+4DEf3Oi4RZcMfq/H6H7MbdpUbBLssudRCbS2QNV6vILQ9uBG64j4wb2CKGAAM2+aw+BYfCpxNSeloQ2BbcnUnOHjk=" />
</div>

    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span id="aOneActualLbl">Assignment 1</span>
            <input name="aOneActualTxt" type="text" value="8" id="aOneActualTxt" /> 
            <span id="aOnePossibleLbl">Possible</span>
            <input name="aOnePossibleTxt" type="text" value="10" id="aOnePossibleTxt" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span id="aTwoActualLbl">Assignment 2</span>
            <input name="aTwoActualTxt" type="text" value="8" id="aTwoActualTxt" /> 
            <span id="aTwoPossibleLbl">Possible</span>
            <input name="aTwoPossibleTxt" type="text" value="10" id="aTwoPossibleTxt" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span id="aThreeActualLbl">Assignment 3</span>
            <input name="aThreeActualTxt" type="text" value="9" id="aThreeActualTxt" /> 
            <span id="aThreePossibleLbl">Possible</span>
            <input name="aThreePossibleTxt" type="text" value="10" id="aThreePossibleTxt" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span id="aFourActualLbl">Assignment 4</span>
            <input name="aFourActualTxt" type="text" value="9" id="aFourActualTxt" /> 
            <span id="aFourPossibleLbl">Possible</span>
            <input name="aFourPossibleTxt" type="text" value="10" id="aFourPossibleTxt" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span id="aFiveActualLbl">Assignment 5</span>
            <input name="aFiveActualTxt" type="text" value="8" id="aFiveActualTxt" /> 
            <span id="aFivePossibleLbl">Possible</span>
            <input name="aFivePossibleTxt" type="text" value="10" id="aFivePossibleTxt" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span id="aSixActualLbl">Assignment 6</span>
            <input name="aSixActualTxt" type="text" value="8" id="aSixActualTxt" /> 
            <span id="aSixPossibleLbl">Possible</span>
            <input name="aSixPossibleTxt" type="text" value="10" id="aSixPossibleTxt" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span id="aSevenActualLbl">Assignment 7</span>
            <input name="aSevenActualTxt" type="text" value="8" id="aSevenActualTxt" /> 
            <span id="aSevenPossibleLbl">Possible</span>
            <input name="aSevenPossibleTxt" type="text" value="10" id="aSevenPossibleTxt" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span id="aEightActualLbl">Assignment 8</span>
            <input name="aEightActualTxt" type="text" value="8" id="aEightActualTxt" /> 
            <span id="aEightPossibleLbl">Possible</span>
            <input name="aEightPossibleTxt" type="text" value="10" id="aEightPossibleTxt" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span id="aNineActualLbl">Assignment 9</span>
            <input name="aNineActualTxt" type="text" value="8" id="aNineActualTxt" /> 
            <span id="aNinePossibleLbl">Possible</span>
            <input name="aNinePossibleTxt" type="text" value="10" id="aNinePossibleTxt" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span id="aTenActualLbl">Assignment 10</span>
            <input name="aTenActualTxt" type="text" value="8" id="aTenActualTxt" /> 
            <span id="aTenPossibleLbl">Possible</span>
            <input name="aTenPossibleTxt" type="text" value="10" id="aTenPossibleTxt" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="runCalculation" value="Calculate Grade" id="runCalculation" />
            <span id="currentGradeLbl">Your current grade is B</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the screenshot below, I would like assignment 2, 3, 6, 7, and 10 to be grey to create the checker effect.  Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to work this out using a single formula but sometimes it's easy if you break them into multiple series.

```
2, 6, 10, 14, ... => 4n-2
3, 7, 11, 15, ... => 4n-1
```

So,

```
.form-group:nth-child(4n-2), .form-group:nth-child(4n-1){
    background: #e4e4e4;
}
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lagzjcs/)

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 did this help in solving your issue?